# How to get desktop folder of specified user in red hat Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

For installation purposes I need to locate desktop folders of all Linux with [Qvwm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qvwm) users on current machine.

I have the following script:

```
HOMES=`getent passwd | cut -d: -f6`
SHORTCUT=/path/to/shortcut.desktop
find $HOMES -maxdepth 3 -name "Desktop" -exec cp $SHORTCUT {} \;
```

But I understood that user desktop folder may differ from "Desktop".

The question is: how I can determine the correct path to desktop folder of all/specified user in system.

Thanks for you suggestions..

Comment: Linux-the-OS doesn't have a concept of "Desktop" at all -- that's specific to the user's individual window manager / desktop environment. Which is to say, there's not guaranteed to even be such a *thing* as a "desktop" for a user account at all.

Comment: I use red hat based linux and elk x windows

Comment: What's "ELK" in this context? I mostly hear the acronym to refer to ElasticSearch/Logstash/Kibana, which obvs. doesn't have anything to do with desktop. X is a generic windowing protocol -- lots of different desktop environments sit on top of it.

Comment: ...that said, if we assume only systems targeting FreeDesktop-compliant desktop environments -- how much do you trust these users? Is it safe to `eval` code they own/control? (To be clear, a user can change their dotfiles to modify their desktop directory by modifying environment variables; sourcing dotfiles of a less-privileged user with a more-privileged shell is a great way to let them take over your account, should they be inclined).

Comment: As above, there may not be a Desktop folder. Maybe you can search for a file that you know for certain should be in any users Desktop folder. Also If  you continue with your current plan, I would add `-type d` to narrow search for the Desktop directory (folder). Hmm, I just searched on my tiny computer, it has `/home/debian/Desktop`, but it is completely empty. Seems like you have try several searches and hope that they cover all cases. Good luck.

Comment: Googling with word elk gives no info about my x windows, I needs one time to go deeper and determine which type of x windows elk based on. Sorry

Comment: "What type of X windows"? X11 is basically a protocol that sits between your display driver and your applications. Everything we care about here (the "desktop environment") is on the application side, not the display-driver side, so it's not related to X11 except so much as it *uses* X11.

Comment: AND, please clarify in your Q, is this meant to fix one machine that you have access to, or is it meant to be part of on install system where the machines are of the same type, or can be different? Good luck.

Comment: "Desktop" is whatever folder the current desktop environment (if any) chooses to use. Also the "home" directory can be anywhere in the filesystem. You can get the home dir from /etc/passwd, however from there, you'll need to do some tests. The user might have multiple desktop environments installed and the only way to tell where the "desktop" dir is is to check each environment's config files and update them all.

Comment: @TerryCarmen, ...the OP *is* already retrieving the home directory the right way (with `getent`, so it works even with accounts coming from LDAP/NIS/etc instead of `/etc/passwd`); it's just the desktop where things are more interesting.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right. Can't fix comment anymore though. Expired

Comment: i found that elk is a Qvwm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qvwm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any desktop environment following the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html) and compatible with the [`xdg-user-dirs` reference implementation](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-user-dirs/tree/), this might look as follows:

```
sudo -u "$user" -i bash -l <<'EOF'
  user_dirs_file=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/user-dirs.dirs
  [[ -s $user_dirs_file ]] && . "$user_dirs_file"
  printf '%s\n' "${XDG_DESKTOP_DIR:-$HOME/Desktop}"
EOF
```

- If `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is set by the user's dotfiles, the configuration file specifying the location of their home directory will be set in the directory thus named; otherwise, the file exists in `~user/.config`.
- If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/user-dirs.dirs` exists and contains an assignment to `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR`, the result of that assignment shall be used as the user's desktop directory.
- If no such file exists, or no such assignment exists, the desktop directory shall be `$HOME/Desktop`.

Comment: Thank you, seems like it exactly I looking for

Comment: BTW, do be careful here if you're deploying this where you don't trust your users -- someone could make their "Desktop" be a location they don't own (or a symlink to such a location); you don't want to write to it from a more-privileged account blindly. Operating on (or using values read from) a user's files only after assuming that user's privileges is often the safer approach.